# Is there a way to search 2 fields with one list box in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

So, Im creating a qlikview dashboard in my spare time to look at stats for UFC fights. I have got the data in an excel spreadsheet as the source and im slowly trying to bring it together.
So part of my data set is obviously that I have 2 fighters for each fight. Trying to link them to a single table results in a circular reference, and trying to filter on just one field doesnt give me all of the results.
Is there a way to filter the 2 fields based on one listbox? Or is there a better way to have the data held in the Excel file? any help or opinions would be appreciated, I'm a novice when it comes to qlikview!

Comment: Please give us the format of your excel-file and some sample code of what you have atm.

Comment: OK, I dont have any code yet, I have tried using list boxes and I guess I would have to use an expression, but I have no idea of how to do it, I have been searching but with absolutely no luck.
In terms of the excel file, I have a fighterID, which is the fighters name without spaces. I have a fightID which is just a number, I have other fields as well, but they are more additional information than keys (things like finish (I.e. dec, tko, sub) finish details (unanimous decision, punches, choke) whether its for a belt, e.t.c)

Comment: OK! Can you post the code from the script editor where you loaded the excel file? Just so we can see what fields you have and how the data model looks like at the moment.

Comment: If you have the data all in one excel table, and if I'm understanding correctly, you could have a table with fighter1 and fighter2 as separately named fields, and then add a Search box to your dashboard and point the search box at both of the fighter fields. That when when someone searches Jon Jones, for example, it will look in both fighter fields and should activate all related fights and related fight info.

Comment: I didnt realise that there was a search feature! (like i said absolute novice) I'll give that a try in a minute!

Comment: LOAD fightID, 
     eventID, 
     fightRedOutcome, 
     fightBlueOutcome, 
     fightWeightCategory, 
     fightCatchweigh, 
     fightIntendedWeight, 
     fightFinish, 
     fightFinishDetails, 
     fightRound, 
     fightMins, 
     fightSeconds, 
     fightTournementBelt, 
     fightBelt, 
     fightTournements, 
     fightInterim, 
     fightVacant, 
     fightUndisputed, 
     redID, 
     blueID
FROM
[C:\Users\morganr\Desktop\UFC\3.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is FIGHT);

redID and blueID are the fighters IDs

Comment: OK I tried the search box and its definitely a step in the right direction, although, Ideally what I would like is when I select something, It takes that as: fighter1 = "jonJones" OR fighter2 = "JonJones" if that makes sense?

Comment: Qlik has triggers you could use to force that to happen, but it does seem a bit wonky. I think traditionally, this would be solved through some data transforming. Your current table structure would be converted into three; a table of all fighters (not linked to fights, just all fighters with no dups), and your fights would be in a separate table with each unique record being a specific fight, then you'd have a mapping table which would have a record for each fight/fighter combo. With this setup, I believe you would be able to get what you want, a single field with all fighters to select from.